# An inequality about the difference of increasing sequences

Tags: inequality

Suppose I have two sequence of positive integers numbers $\{a_1, a_2, ...\}$ and $\{b_1, b_2, b_3,...\}$ such that $a_1^4 - 2\cdot b_1^4 > 1$ and $a_i > b_i$ and $a_{i+1} > a_i$ and $b_{i+1} > b_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_{i+1} - b_{i+1} > a_i - b_i$. That is, the difference between two numbers increases as we move on in the sequence.

I would like to show that $a_{i+1}^4 - 2 \cdot b_{i+1}^4 > a_i^4 - 2 \cdot b_i^4$

It seems rather clear that this inequality must hold, but unfortunately I cannot come up with a proof.

This is what I have tried:

$a_i > b_i$ implies $a_i^4 > b_i^4$. We can deduce $a_{i+1}^4 - b_{i+1}^4 > a_i^{2} - b_i^4$. But I don't think it necessarily follows that $a_{i+1}^4 - 2\cdot b_{i+1}^4 > a_i^{4} - 2\cdot b_i^4$. I think I need to use the fact $a_1^4 - 2 \cdot b_1^4 > 1$, but I am not sure how that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(a,b)=a^4-2b^4$. The gist is that the sequences are both getting larger *and* the difference is increasing. I think you can prove separately that $f(a+1,b+1)>f(a,b)$ for any $a,b$, and it should be quite self-evident that $f(a+k,b)>f(a,b)$ for any $k>0$.

The first claim requires some algebraic calculation:
$$f(a+1,b+1)=(a+1)^4-2(b+1)^4=a^4-2b^4+(...)-(...)=\dots>a^4-2b^4$$
under the conditions $a>b$ and $a^4-2b^4>1$ (hopefully! try proving this).

From there, it's just a matter of induction: we want to know that $f(a_{i+1},b_{i+1})>f(a_i,b_i)$. If $c:=b_{i+1}-b_i$ and $d:=a_{i+1}-(a_i-c)$ then our assumptions tell us that $c,d>0$ and then $f(a_{i+1},b_{i+1})=f(a_i+d+c,b_i+c)>f(a_i,b_i)$ by the application of our first result $c$ times and our second result $d$ times.

(When posted, the question didn't say that the sequences themselves were increasing, which leads to a counterexample like this:

- Let $a_1=3$, $b_1=2$. Then $a_1^4-2b_1^4=3^4-2\times4^4=81-2\times16=49$.
- Let $a_2=2$, $b_2=0$. This is permitted because $a_2-b_2=2>1=a_1-b_1$. Then $a_2^4-2b_2^4=16-2\times0=16$.)